# Django: Saving Foreign Key from Form

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys, django-formwizard

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167076/django-filtering-queryset-from-two-model-fields) in which I am trying to figure out how to construct a PointField composed of lat / lon FloatFields. I have taken @Simon's advice and restructured my model to look like this:

```
class Point(models.Model):
   lat = models.FloatField()
   lon = models.FloatField()

class Thing(models.Model):
   point = models.ForeignKey(Point)
```

My form has two fields corresponding to values from google maps' longitude and latitude coordinates:

```
class StepThreeForm(forms.Form):
    lat = forms.FloatField()
    lon = forms.FloatField()
    ...
```

However, this does not work for obvious reasons, but I am not sure how to fix it. To clarify, I am trying to have two form fields corresponding to the foreign key values of `lat` and `lon`. Here is the supplementary information (I am using a FormWizard and forms.Form):

---

```
url(r'^mapform/$', login_required(MyWizard.as_view([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm, StepThreeForm])), name='create'),

class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):  ## this view also serves to edit existing objects and provide their instances
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
        try:
            thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=id)
            instance = thing
        except:
            thing = None
            instance = None
        if thing and thing.user != self.request.user:
            raise HttpResponseForbidden()
        if not thing:
            instance = Thing()
            for form in form_list:
                for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                    setattr(instance, field, value)
            instance.user = self.request.user
            instance.save()
        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
                'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
```

I appreciate any and all advice and help!

---

EDIT: Update based on Yuji Tomita's input. Most of it made a lot of sense (Thank you!), but I'm not sure why it results in a ValueError.

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
     ....
            for form in form_list:
                form.save(instance)
     ...

class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
     ...
     def save(self, thing):
        for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            setattr(thing, field, value)

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
     ...
     def save(self, thing):
        for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            setattr(thing, field, value)
```

I believe that I should keep the form fields as lat and lon, because I am using a google map in my form and taking the lat and lon from a selected input, then constructing a point fields from those values:

```
class StepThreeForm(forms.Form):
    lat = forms.FloatField()
    lon = forms.FloatField()

    def save(self, thing):
        thing.point = Point.objects.get_or_create(lat=self.cleaned_data.get('lat'), lon=self.cleaned_data.get('lon'))
```

This yields a `ValueError: Cannot assign "(<Point: Point object>, False)": "Thing.point" must be a "Point" instance.`

```
Traceback:
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  223.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  286.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in render_done
  328.         done_response = self.done(final_form_list, **kwargs)
File "/myproject/myapp/forms.py" in done
  93.       form.save(instance)
File "/myproject/myapp/forms.py" in save
  67.         thing.point = Thing.objects.get_or_create(lat=self.cleaned_data.get('lat'), lon=self.cleaned_data.get('lon'))
File "/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __set__
  366.                                  self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
```

Comment: Please edit your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167076/django-filtering-queryset-from-two-model-fields) instead of spreading it over multiple threads.

Comment: My understanding was that if a question was asking different things than the original, that I should start a new question. The former question was concerning how to `filter` based on two separate model fields. It was answered. This topic is different because it is asking how to save `ForeignKey` fields from a form, a completely different exercise than filtering based on the combination of two model fields. If I am mistaken I would appreciate a moderator to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: @NickB, you're totally okay here. We all make sudden assumptions when reading posts. Thanks for being civil about it!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misunderstood the intent of your second thread. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sure no problem I appreciate the feedback. I genuinely wanted to know if I was violating the terms of the forum, and I appreciate the clarification! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend building a `save` method on each of your forms which knows how to save itself to the database. It follows a general pattern that "the form performs its action via form.save()" so it should be intuitive to follow.

The bottom line is that right now you have a blanket: "for every field in all forms, set the Thing attribute to those fields".

Since in reality you have per-form save behavior, I think it makes sense to require passing the instance to each form so that each form has a chance to save data in the way appropriate for its fields.

```
class Form1(...):
   def save(self, thing):
      for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
          setattr(thing, field, value)

class Form2(...):
   def save(self, thing):
      thing.point = Point.objects.get_or_create(lat=self.cleaned_data.get('lat'), long=...)
      # note, you may not want get_or_create if you don't want to share points.
```

Your view would then become:

```
for form in form_list:
    form.save(instance)
```

Just an idea.

If you want to be more DRY about it and like the automation of your other forms, I'd build a base form which has a save method already defined:

```
class BaseSaveBehaviorForm(forms.Form):
     def save(self, thing):
         for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
             setattr(thing, field, value)

class NormalBehaviorForm(BaseSaveBehaviorForm):
     # your forms as usual


class SpecialSaveBehaviorForm(forms.Form):
     def save(self, instance):
         # do something unusual
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot that is very helpful and helps further explain what is going on in the forms. Thank you! I think that I have implemented it incorrectly, however, as my attempt has resulted in a `ValueError`. If you have a moment it would be cool to get your input on what I may have done wrong, but if you are too busy I understand also. Thanks again!

Comment: @NickB, no problem. The error is my fault, get_or_create returns the instance and a created or not flag. You should be assigning `thing.point = Point.objects.create(lat=lat, long=long)` or `thing.point = ...get_or_create()[0]`

Comment: Thanks for your patient assistance. I learned a lot from your explanation and am now able to properly save the object in the FormWizard! Thanks again!