# Django: Updating Object in Forms with Custom Save Method

Tags: python, django, forms, save, instance

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188908/django-saving-foreign-key-from-form), in which I learned how to over-ride the `save` method of a multi-step formwizard to save form fields differently in different forms. Thanks to @Yuji Tomita's help, I figured out how to save the forms correctly. At this point, however, I am lost on how to update the instance and save changes to the object.

I have tried to follow the logic I learned from @Yuji, but have not been able to properly update the object.

This is where I am:

```
class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
     ...
     def save(self, thing):
        for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            setattr(thing, field, value)

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
     ...
     def save(self, thing):
        for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            setattr(thing, field, value)

class StepThreeForm(forms.Form):
     ...
     def save(self, thing):
         thing.point = Point.objects.get_or_create(latitude=self.cleaned_data.get('latitude'), longitude=self.cleaned_data.get('longitude'))[0]
         for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
             setattr(thing, field, value)
```

Here is how I have over-written the wizard's done method to save the instances:

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
        try:
            thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=id)
            instance = thing
        except:
            thing = None
            instance = None
        if thing and thing.user != self.request.user:
            raise HttpResponseForbidden()
        if not thing:
            instance = Thing()
            for form in form_list:
                form.save(instance)
            instance.user = self.request.user
            instance.save()
        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
                'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
```

How should I change my `save` method so that I can properly update the `thing` instance? Thanks for your ideas!

---

EDIT: Adding the view that edits the object:

```
def edit_wizard(request, id):
    thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=id)
    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        initial = {'0': {'id': thing.id,
                       'year': thing.year,
                       'color': thing.color,
                       ... #listing form fields individually to populate the initial_dict for the instance
                       },
                   '1': {image': thing.main_image,
                       ...
                       },
                   '2': {description': thing.additional_description,
                       'latitude': thing.point.latitude,  #thing has a foreign key to point that records lat and lon
                       'longitude': thing.point.longitude,
                       },
                    }

        form = MyWizard.as_view([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm, StepThreeForm], initial_dict=initial)
        return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request)
```

Comment: Do you run instance.save() after all this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mariodev. I am running `instance.save()` in the done method of my formwizard. I have included that information above in an edit. Thanks for any ideas that may help me figure out this difficult problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is problem that you are seeing? Get error or object is not saved?

Probably the indentation in your `done()` method is not correct, so its not calling the `form.save()`. It should be like :

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        ... 
        #existing code

        if not thing:
            instance = Thing()

        #this is moved out of if
        for form in form_list:
            form.save(instance)

        instance.user = self.request.user
        instance.save()
        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
                'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
```

Comment: You are right that was the problem. I'm not sure why but I had to change the save method on only the third form to `def save(self, thing):` instead of `def save(self, instance):` The other two forms I used `def save(self, instance):`  Any idea why? Either way thank you very much!

Comment: @NickB, if its model form, then it would have `instance` attribute which might be causing the confusion. But not sure thats the case.